# Quantity Selector / Input for WooCommerce Mini Cart

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to display a quantity selector for each product in the WooCommerce mini cart and I've managed to get this code together (which is not working, there's nothing showing).

Am I using the wrong hook or something?
Here's the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_minicart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_minicart( $html, $product ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    return $html;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is a real development, something too broad for stackOverFlow. You can't make it work like it is actually for many reasons:

- There are some mistakes in your code regarding the hook arguments variables...
- You can't have a submit button for each quantity imput field and You can't have also a `<form>` for each cart item: If you look in cart page, there is only one button that update all quantities changes via ajax *(and only one form for all cart items)*.
- **Updating quantities:** An update button should be needed for all cart items or a behavior that will update each quantity on input change.
- **Ajax is required** to update quantities and to refresh cart fragments, so it's something complicated that require jQuery, Wordpress Ajax…

Now to get the quantity fields displayed you can use the following *(making some changes in the CSS rules - styling)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', 'add_minicart_quantity_fields', 10, 3 );
function add_minicart_quantity_fields( $html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $cart_item['data'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    return woocommerce_quantity_input( array('input_value' => $cart_item['quantity']), $cart_item['data'], false ) . $product_price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works just for the display.

You will need much more code and changes to get that working. There is  [WooCommerce Better Usability](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-better-usability/) plugin that you could try.

> See: [Woocommerce Mini Cart Widget Change Quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846270/woocommerce-mini-cart-widget-change-quantity)

Comment: what would it cost (estimate) to make this? Can you make it?